# Using Vue.js prototype returns undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to make an instance of a js service that is a class so that I can import in and use it everywhere in my project by doing so in my main.js:

```
import MultibaasProvider from './services/multibaas-provider'
Vue.prototype.$service = MultibaasProvider;
```

Then I am importing it in my component like this:

```
<script>
import LeftSideTabs from '../components/LeftSideTabs'
const services = new this.$service(this.apiKey);

alert(services)
export default {
    components: {
        LeftSideTabs
    },
    data() {
      return {
        apiKey: this.$store.state.apiKey
      }
    }

}
</script>
```

and I get Cannot read property '$service' of undefined

What am I doing wrong, how can I import it and use it in every component.

Answer (score 1):

You should use that `$service` inside the component context which is available inside the exported script options `export default {...}`, this works if you call it inside a lifecycle hook or a method any other property :

```
<script>
import LeftSideTabs from '../components/LeftSideTabs'

export default {
    components: {
        LeftSideTabs
    },
    data() {
      return {
        apiKey: this.$store.state.apiKey
      }
    },
   mounted(){
     const services = new this.$service(this.apiKey);

     alert(services)
  }

}
</script>
```